# Python sockets with flask and vue for continious serial data stream

Tags: python, sockets, flask

So I have an flask application which is extended by the `flask_socketio` package.

I currently have a vue front end, that connects to an socket.

Now the output of the socket connection in the following:

[image: socket connection vue]

I also see an connection in the terminal of the flask application:

`127.0.0.1 - - [23/Aug/2019 21:07:11] "GET /socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=Mo_u1wR HTTP/1.1" 200`

However, I have on my code that when the socket connects, there should start an thread with while `true`, to continious receive the data.

This is the code I have:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
from flask_socketio import SocketIO, send, emit
import threading
from threading import Lock
import time
import controllers.gpsController

# configuration
DEBUG = True

# instantiate the app
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)
thread = None
thread_lock = Lock()
async_mode = None
# app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secret!'

# enable CORS
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*', async_mode=async_mode)

def activate_gps():
    ser = controllers.gpsController.open_serial_connection()
    while True:
        data = controllers.gpsController.readGPS(ser)
        if data != None:
            socketio.emit('fetch_gps_data', data, broadcast=True)
            socketio.sleep(0.1)

# Use sockets here
@socketio.on('connect')
def start_get_data_thread():
    global thread
    with thread_lock:
        if thread is None:
            thread = socketio.start_background_task(target=activate_gps)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    socketio.run(app, host='127.0.0.1', port=12345)
```

Anyone an idea what I'm doing wrong here? If I have te code of `activate_gps()` in another file and call that, I get the wanted output.